# Link for action problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have problem with my application.

I have table report, there are 2 column , user_id and comment_id
I created link on article comment view

```
<%= link_to "[ ! ]", report_comment_url(comment) %>
```

---

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def report
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment = CommentReport.new(params[:comment_report, :comment_id])
    if @comment_report.save
      redirect_to :back
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

but it was error

ActionController::MethodNotAllowed

Only post requests are allowed.

Do you have any suggestion how to post current_user id and comment_id to report table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what I assume you're trying to accomplish, I'd suggest you use link_to_remote.

Comment: <%= link_to "[ ! ]", report_comment_url(comment), :comment_id => comment.id, :user_id => comment.user_id %> 

I have tried this
def report
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment_report = CommentReport.new(params[:comment_report])
    if @comment_report.save
      redirect_to :back
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
i was to try that code. but the result is 
id  user_id  comment_id
5  NULL  NULL

how I get params user_id and comment_id

Comment: When adding parameters they must go in the url helper, additional arguments to link_to are treated as html attributes. You wan to do this: `<%= link_to "[ ! ]", report_comment_url(comment, :comment_report => {:comment_id => comment.id, :user_id => comment.user_id })%>

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's going on:

Using Restful routes, you've set up report as a post operation. Which seems reasonable because report is performing the create action.

Unfortunately link_to doesn't know or even care about that. Links in general only perform get requests. Forms produce post requests, but they seem unnecessary in this case.

You have four options.

1. Make the [ ! ] link a button on a form submitting to report.
2. Break RESTful guidelines and redefine report receive get requests.
3. Make this a link_to_remote call. N.B. This relies on javascript and will not work at all if Javascript is disabled.
4. Add the method options to the link_to call. N.B. This also relies on javascript and will fall back to a get request if javascript is disabled.

   ```
   <%= link_to "[ ! ]", report_comment_url(comment), :method => :post %>
   ```

However none of these solutions will solve all your problems. There are a couple of bugs with your posted code that you may not have realized yet.

First:

```
@comment = CommentReport.new(params[:comment_report, :comment_id])
```

is bad syntax and will fail. There are a number of ways to fix this, the preferred method is to to roll :comment_id into the params[:comment_report] hash to fix this.

Ie pass the params as:

```
params = {
  :id => 4,  # done by report_comment_url
  :comment_report => {
     :attribute1 => value1,
     ...
     :comment_id => 4
  }
}
```

Now you can use

```
@comment = CommentReport.new(params[:comment_report])
```

for the desired effect.

Second:
report_comment_url does not pass along the additional parameters, so your controller will try to save an empty record. Adding the comment_report to the arguments of report_comment_url will fix this problem.

This will perform a remote call requesting the report action in the comments controller, with the parameter hash required to fix the other problem.

```
 <%= link_to_remote "[ ! ]", report_comment_url(comment, 
   :comment_report => {:attribute1 => value1, ..., :comment_id => comment.id}),
   :method => :post %>
```

Answer (score 0):

params[:comment_report] is nil because there's no reference to that in your link_to statement. Since you mention in the comment that your view is:

```
<%= link_to "[ ! ]", report_comment_url(comment), :comment_id => comment.id, :user_id => comment.user_id %>
```

Then you need this in your controller:

```
@comment_report = CommentReport.new(:user_id => params[:user_id], :comment_id => params[:comment_id])
```

But I agree with NSD that link_to_remote would work better for what you want to accomplish (which is create a new record and return the user to the page). You would also eliminate the need for your @comment = Comment.find(params[:id]) statement.